# Need help decoding ?base64?

Tags: php, text, base64, enigma2

Me and my group are currently trying to decrypt certain messages for a big school project but we just cant figure it out! the idea is that someone "hacked" our raspberry pi and left tons of breadcrumbs that we have to resolve but we get stuck on this piece of text:

V2VsY29tZQ==
VGxSTVRRPT0=
VWtWTk5FOUVSVEJSZWxFd1RWVlpNRkpxWkVWUmExWkRUVVJWTTFGNlp6Vk9NRmw2VVZSS1IxRnFUWFpQVlVwRlRXdE5lbEV3UlhoUmFrMHhVbFJuZVUxclZrTlBSR3N4VG5wU1JrNTZhekZTVlZsM1RucG5QUT09
V1RCak1XUXlVbGxUVjJScVlsVTFkbGx1YkVKbFJURkZVVmRrV2sweFJqUlVWVkpDWkZadmVXUkhORDA9
Vmtab2QxVnJOVVpOV0VaWVYwWmFUMXBXVW01bFJsSllZMFphVGsxRVZsVlVhMmgzVkZkV2NrMVVWbFZOUmtwRFdsWldOR05XVGxsWGF6VnNZa1ZaTVZaR1ZrNU5SVEZ5WlVSYVdrMHpRbEJaVjNSV1pXeFNTR05GTld0aGVsWkdWMjV3UjFSWFJuTmlSRXBWVm14S2VWUlVRVEZXVmtaWlZtczVhRlpIWXpVPQ==
Vm10U1IxVXhUblJXYmtwT1ZteGFVMVl3V21GVlJsWlpZMGMxYkZac1NucFdWM2hMVkRGYVZXSkZWbFZoTW1oNlZrWmtWMk15UlhwaFJsWm9UVlZ3V0Zkc1dsZE9SMDVYVTJ4c1dHRjZWbk5aVkVvelRXeGFSMkZJWkZaaVZrcFhWRlpTVDFWV1drVlJWR3M5
Vm0xMFlXSXlVWGxVYmtwT1ZteHdVVlpzV21GaU1WSlZVbTFHVmxKc1dsaFdWbWhyVlVaV1ZVMUVhejA9
Vm0weE1GVXhSWGhXV0doVVlteEtXRmxVUm5kVlJscDBaVWRHYVUxV1NsWlZiVEZIVm14S2MyTkdjRnBOUjAweFZrUkdTMk14VG5GU2JIQk9VbXhXTkZaclpEUlpWbHBZVTJ0YVYySkdXbTlVVnpGdlRsWmFWbGRyV2xCV2EwcFRWVVpSZDFCUlBUMD0=
Vm0wd2VFMUhSWGROVldSWFYwZG9XVmx0ZUV0V01WbDNXa1pPVmxac2NEQmFWV1JIVmpGYWMySkVUbGROYWtaSVZteFZlRmRXUm5OaFJtUlhUVEpvVFZkV1VrSmxSbGw0Vkc1S2FsSnVRazlWYlhoMlpXeGFjbHBJY0d4U2EzQllWVEo0VjFaSFNrZGpTRUpXWVd0d2RscFdXbUZqYkdSMFpFWk9UbUY2VmpWV1JscGhWakZWZVZOclpGaGlSMmhXVm01d1YxUXhjRVZTYlVaVFRWaENTbGt3VlRWV01rVjZVV3h3VjFZemFIWmFSRVp6VmpGT2RWTnNVbWxTTVVwdlZtMXdUMkl4VFhoVmJGcFlZbFZhVkZscmFFTlRiR1J5VjJ4a2FGWnJjRmRaTUZwVFZqRmFWMk5HVG1GU1JWcEVWbGQ0UTFaVk1VVk5SREE5

the first sentence is "welcome" from base64 but if you try to decode any random part of the rest it doesn't give you anything.

Can someone help us?
thanks!

Comment: It seems to be repeatedly base64-encoded, with a mix of other encodings thrown in. I can't figure out the second one, but the third one is `rot13`'d and seems to mean *something*: `cache epub 100 pg100.txt`.

Comment: While I don't think this is totally relevant for SO< I do find it an interesting challenge. :)

Comment: Do you think the encoding are seperated by the "="?

Comment: Thank you very much by the way!

Comment: It seems to be separated by newline. The `=`s are part of base64.

Comment: The `=` is the padding for base64. The second one is "NTLM" if you run it through a base 64 decoder twice.

Comment: **#4:** `34826.3/52575.3/32802.2/3420.6/73617.3/485.6/19750.6/`

Comment: SO sort of mixed up the newlines, but we tried every rot on all of the text, but none of the rot's seem to make sense... I'm even amazed that you managed to find that haha!

Comment: #4 is just repeatedly passed through a base64 encoding.

Comment: @Bytewave how did you figure out #3? **nvm** I was copying too much, which was breaking the encoding.

Comment: @wheeler Guessed it was rot13 based on how gibberish it looked once it was off the base64.

Comment: @Bytewave I think you mean that's the **4th** one, as it looks like the whitespace is the separation between the different "clues". The first two are on the same line and the third one is `VWtWTk5FOUVSVEJSZWxFd1RWVlpNRkpxWkVWUmExWkRUVVJWTTFGNlp6Vk9NRmw2VVZSS1IxRnFUWFpQVlVwRlRXdE5lbEV3UlhoUmFrMHhVbFJuZVUxclZrTlBSR3N4VG5wU1JrNTZhekZTVlZsM1RucG5QUT09 `

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. I need to copy all this into a text document to work on it better at some point.

Comment: @Thomas do you think you could format this a little better to differentiate the different "clues"?

Comment: We are currently trying to decode it with 4 people with rot, base64, jpeg but everything seems to be the same frustrating outcome *sigh*

Comment: I put it in a pastebin, separated by whitespace. Quick and dirty job, should help though. https://pastebin.com/bDfaYR5G

Comment: here is a link to the file as we found it hidden somewhere bit.ly/2oLCGK4

Comment: While this may be a nice puzzle, I'm voting to close this. As noted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134806/puzzles-hidden-answers), SO isn't a place for code puzzles.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 4):

Formatted the question a little better:

1. `V2VsY29tZQ==`
2. `VGxSTVRRPT0=`
3. `VWtWTk5FOUVSVEJSZWxFd1RWVlpNRkpxWkVWUmExWkRUVVJWTTFGNlp6Vk9NRmw2VVZSS1IxRnFUWFpQVlVwRlRXdE5lbEV3UlhoUmFrMHhVbFJuZVUxclZrTlBSR3N4VG5wU1JrNTZhekZTVlZsM1RucG5QUT09`
4. `V1RCak1XUXlVbGxUVjJScVlsVTFkbGx1YkVKbFJURkZVVmRrV2sweFJqUlVWVkpDWkZadmVXUkhORDA9`
5. `Vmtab2QxVnJOVVpOV0VaWVYwWmFUMXBXVW01bFJsSllZMFphVGsxRVZsVlVhMmgzVkZkV2NrMVVWbFZOUmtwRFdsWldOR05XVGxsWGF6VnNZa1ZaTVZaR1ZrNU5SVEZ5WlVSYVdrMHpRbEJaVjNSV1pXeFNTR05GTld0aGVsWkdWMjV3UjFSWFJuTmlSRXBWVm14S2VWUlVRVEZXVmtaWlZtczVhRlpIWXpVPQ==`
6. `Vm10U1IxVXhUblJXYmtwT1ZteGFVMVl3V21GVlJsWlpZMGMxYkZac1NucFdWM2hMVkRGYVZXSkZWbFZoTW1oNlZrWmtWMk15UlhwaFJsWm9UVlZ3V0Zkc1dsZE9SMDVYVTJ4c1dHRjZWbk5aVkVvelRXeGFSMkZJWkZaaVZrcFhWRlpTVDFWV1drVlJWR3M5`
7. `Vm0xMFlXSXlVWGxVYmtwT1ZteHdVVlpzV21GaU1WSlZVbTFHVmxKc1dsaFdWbWhyVlVaV1ZVMUVhejA9`
8. `Vm0weE1GVXhSWGhXV0doVVlteEtXRmxVUm5kVlJscDBaVWRHYVUxV1NsWlZiVEZIVm14S2MyTkdjRnBOUjAweFZrUkdTMk14VG5GU2JIQk9VbXhXTkZaclpEUlpWbHBZVTJ0YVYySkdXbTlVVnpGdlRsWmFWbGRyV2xCV2EwcFRWVVpSZDFCUlBUMD0=`
9. `Vm0wd2VFMUhSWGROVldSWFYwZG9XVmx0ZUV0V01WbDNXa1pPVmxac2NEQmFWV1JIVmpGYWMySkVUbGROYWtaSVZteFZlRmRXUm5OaFJtUlhUVEpvVFZkV1VrSmxSbGw0Vkc1S2FsSnVRazlWYlhoMlpXeGFjbHBJY0d4U2EzQllWVEo0VjFaSFNrZGpTRUpXWVd0d2RscFdXbUZqYkdSMFpFWk9UbUY2VmpWV1JscGhWakZWZVZOclpGaGlSMmhXVm01d1YxUXhjRVZTYlVaVFRWaENTbGt3VlRWV01rVjZVV3h3VjFZemFIWmFSRVp6VmpGT2RWTnNVbWxTTVVwdlZtMXdUMkl4VFhoVmJGcFlZbFZhVkZscmFFTlRiR1J5VjJ4a2FGWnJjRmRaTUZwVFZqRmFWMk5HVG1GU1JWcEVWbGQ0UTFaVk1VVk5SREE5`

This is what I have so far (answer followed by steps to decode):

1. `Welcome` (base64)
2. `NTLM` (2x base64)
3. `DC8814C441F4F7DBEB057C897F3A2FB3/9BD2C3CA1B35E822EB89574E795EF078` (3x base64)
4. `cache epub 100 pg100.txt` (4x base64 -> rot13)
5. `34826.3/52575.3/32802.2/3420.6/73617.3/485.6/19750.6/` (5x base64)
6. `92310.4/65498.2/65452.1/32334.3` (6x base64)
7. `39589.4` (7x base64)
8. `81159.5/17358.2` (8x base64)
9. `45092.3.4/27310.3.2/68909.1.3` (9x base64)

Just some working thoughts:

- #3 seems like it could be decoded further, perhaps it's two hex representations of ASCII or decimal separated by a `/`.
- The numbers seems like either math or coordinates or something separated by `/`s.

**Update:**

- #4 Appears to be a reference to a `txt` version of a book, specifically `The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Complete Works of William Shakespeare`. If you take #4 and google it, you should be able to find it. This leads me to believe that the rest of the numbers are encoded as `line#.word#/line#.word#/...`
- <s>As indicated by Thomas, the first part of line 3 refers to a word in [this](http://gencyber.ialab.dsu.edu/2015/Electives/Password_Kitteh/pw-fake-nt.txt) text file. Open it, perform a search for the first part of line 3, and next to it is the word Caesar, which is referring to the `rot13` cipher being used in the following clue.</s>
- Those numbers are actually hashes of NTLM passwords. The solution for line 3 is `caesar/thirteen` does in fact refer to the `rot13` simple cipher, which is used in the following clue.

**Update 2:**

Ok, if my theory above is true, then the lines 5 through 8 are:

5. `If/you/have/made/it/this/far`
6. `then/We/congratulate/you`
7. `regards`
8. `team/Hydra`

Line 9 was a little harder, as the last digit probably refers to the letter number in the word, so it could be translated as:

9. `P/w/C`

**Final update:**

`PwC` probably refers to [PricewaterhouseCoopers](https://www.google.com/search?q=pwc), which is a multinational consulting company. If you search `team hydra pwc`, you get some [results](https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&q=team+hydra+pwc) that indicate an office of PwC in Hydra, Algeria.

Or, `team hydra` could refer to the [Android hacking group](https://github.com/Team-Hydra/).

Anything further is speculative.

Comment: this is brilliant!

Comment: Now off to a mission on working out what this is...

Comment: #4 refers to a ebook, specifically `The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Complete Works of William Shakespeare`

Comment: The rest of them seem like lines/word numbers in the book.

Comment: Caesar probably refers to `rot13`, its a [simple cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) whose concept was first used in ancient Rome

Comment: @Thomas Specifically, how did you determine that?

Comment: you are a genius!!!

Comment: we are really grateful, just one more piece and its done!

Comment: @Thomas NTLM passwords can be easily cracked.  You can put both hashes in this website and they decode to caeser and thirteen.  https://hashkiller.co.uk/ntlm-decrypter.aspx

Comment: Edited the answer to add some speculation around the meaning of the message.

Comment: hello wheeler! would you mind putting your replies private or hidden for the next two days? this was asked by our lector since other groups have to either find their own solution or perform likewise steps, Thanks! and again, thank you so much! you were of great great help!

Comment: @Thomas Sure, but you will need to remind me otherwise I will forget. Furthermore, if this answer is satisfactory, please mark it as accepted.